# Replace a CSS sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am using an script which uses a remote file.css. I want to add a local file.css in order to override some remote.css styles.

Any suggestion of how could I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use the new styles *instead*, you can find the `link` element and just replace the `href` with the path to the other file. Like this:

```js
document.querySelector("link[href=style.css]").href = "path/to/new/file.css";
```

If you want to override some styles, you'll need to make sure the new file is loaded **after** the first and then either use more specific selecors or `!important`. You can't really "edit" the file in the browser before loading it though, which is what it sounds like you might be asking about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that the script app load a app-style.css which isn't in my code lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the css and not to replace all the css, you can use inline style or you can use bootstrap.
For example:

…

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.